# Best way to get 1st record per partition: FIRST_VALUE vs ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am looking for the fastest way to  get the 1st record (columns a,b,c ) for every partition (a,b) using SQL. Table is  ~10, 000, 000 rows.

Approach #1:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a,b,c, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION by a, b ORDER BY date DESC) as row_num
    FROM T 
) WHERE row_num =1
```

But it probably does extra work behind the scene  - I need only 1st row per partition.

Approach #2  using FIRST_VALUE(). Since FIRST_VALUE() returns expression
let pack/concatenate a,b,c using some separator into single expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(a+','+'b'+','+c) 
OVER ( PARTITION by a, b ORDER BY date  DESC rows unbounded preceding) FROM T
```

But in this case I need to unpack the result, which is extra step.

Approach #3  using FIRST_VALUE() - repeat OVER (...) for a , b :

```
SELECT 
FIRST_VALUE(a) 
OVER ( PARTITION by a, b ORDER BY date  DESC rows unbounded preceding),
FIRST_VALUE(b) 
OVER ( PARTITION by a, b ORDER BY date  DESC rows unbounded preceding),
c 
FROM T
```

In approach #3 I do not know if database engine (Redshift) smart enough to partition only once

Comment: have you actually tried running those? We don't have very tight performance requirements, and often use approach #3 even with event 10 columns using same window. I was always convinced that the query engine is smart enough to notice the same window definition and is able to re-use (no evidence though). Also what we usually do is `SELECT DISTINCT` + `window functions over columns` - otherwise you get tons of duplicates

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the queries? I am curious what are the performance implications of each solution.

Comment: "*I need only 1st row per partition*" you seem to expect some shortcut possibility of the database here. That is no the case. In order to reliably find the "first row" the database has no alternative to sort all rows in the partition, it can't take a shortcut. If you want to know which alternative is the fastest, check the execution plan. Btw: another option would be to use a join against a derived table: https://pastebin.com/z7CV7FKD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is different from the other two. The first only returns one row per group. The other two return the same rows as in the original query.

You should use the version that does what you want, which I presume is the first one. If you add `select distinct` or `group by` to the other queries, that will probably add overhead that will make them slower -- but you can test on your data to see if that is true.

Your intuition is correct that the first query does unnecessary work.  In databases that support indexes fully, a correlated subquery is often faster. I don't think that would be the case in Redshift, however.